# Почему параметр index после выполнения рекурсии начинает движение в обратном порядке?

Tags: javascript

объясните пожалуйста, почему так происходит?

https://codepen.io/Jane111/pen/LYJWKZp

Проблема на 9 строке (codepen)

Прошу не советовать сделать циклом, умею, просто изучаю рекурсию, пытаюсь разобраться.

Спасибо!

```js
const arr = ['Аня', 'Игорь', 'Марина', 'Коля']

function printArr(arr, index = 0) {
  console.log(arr[index]);
  index = index + 1
  
  if (index < arr.length) {
    printArr(arr, index)
    console.log(index);
  } 
}

printArr(arr)
```

Comment: А в чём собственно заключается вопрос?

Comment: @Miha в заголовке вопрос)

Comment: Условно, "вторые" console.log складываются в стэк. 1 итерация - вывели имя, (рекурсия ->) и переходим к 2 - вывели имя, (рекурсия ->) переходим к 3 = вывели имя, (рекурсия ->) переходим 4 - вывели имя и по условию не попадаем, возвращаемся к 3 шагу и выводим там индекс - код закончился, возвращаемся к 2 шагу - выводим там индекс - код закончился - возвращаемся к 1 шагу и выводим индекс

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = ['Аня', 'Игорь', 'Марина', 'Коля']

function printArr(arr, index = 0) {
  console.log(arr[index]);
  index = index + 1
  
  if (index < arr.length) {
    console.log(index); // Поменял местами
    printArr(arr, index)

  } 
}

printArr(arr)
```

Почему в вашем примере сначала выводятся все имена, а лишь затем индексы?

Потому что это так работает. Когда выполнение доходит до рекурсивного вызова `printArr(arr, index)`, то выполнение текущего `printArr` как бы замирает. В итоге получается что-то такое:

```
printArr() {
    printArr() {
        printArr() {
            console.log(3)
        }
        console.log(2)
    }
    console.log(1)
}
```